# FFmpeg extracts black image from H264 stream

Tags: c#, video, ffmpeg, h.264

I have a C# application that receives H264 stream through a socket. I want to continuously get the latest image from that stream.

Here's what I did with FFmpeg 5.0.1, just a rough sample to get ONE latest image, how I start FFmpeg:

```
var ffmpegInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(FFMPEG_PATH);
ffmpegInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
ffmpegInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
ffmpegInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
ffmpegInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

ffmpegInfo.Arguments = "-i pipe: -f h264 -pix_fmt bgr24 -an -sn pipe:";

ffmpegInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
ffmpegInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

Process myFFmpeg = new Process();
myFFmpeg.StartInfo = ffmpegInfo;
myFFmpeg.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
myFFmpeg.Start();

var inStream = myFFmpeg.StandardInput.BaseStream;
FileStream baseStream = myFFmpeg.StandardOutput.BaseStream as FileStream;
myFFmpeg.BeginErrorReadLine();
```

Then I start a new thread to receive the stream through socket:

```
// inStream is "myFFmpeg.StandardInput.BaseStream" from the code block above
var t = Task.Run(() => ReceiveStream(inStream));
```

Next I read the output from FFmpeg:

```
byte[] decoded = new byte[Width * Height * 3];
int numBytesToRead = Width * Height * 3;
int numBytesRead = 0;

while (numBytesToRead > 0)
{
   int n = baseStream.Read(decoded, 0, decoded.Length);
   Console.WriteLine($"Read {n} bytes");
   if (n == 0)
   {
      break;
   }              
      numBytesRead += n;
      numBytesToRead -= n;
}
```

Lastly, I use ImageSharp library to save `decoded` byte array as a jpeg file.

```
image.Save("test.jpeg", encoder);
```

However, `test.jpeg` always comes out as a black image. What did I do wrong?
Here's the stderr log that I got from ffmpeg:

```
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/bt470bg/smpte170m, progressive), 1080x2256, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Incompatible pixel format 'bgr24' for codec 'libx264', auto-selecting format 'yuv444p'
[libx264 @ 0x11b9068f0] using cpu capabilities: ARMv8 NEON
[libx264 @ 0x11b9068f0] profile High 4:4:4 Predictive, level 5.0, 4:4:4, 8-bit
Output #0, h264, to 'pipe:':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf59.16.100
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264, yuv444p(tv, smpte170m/bt470bg/smpte170m, progressive), 1080x2256, q=2-31, 25 fps, 25 tbn
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc59.18.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
frame=   56 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x
frame=   87 fps= 83 q=28.0 size=     370kB time=00:00:01.16 bitrate=2610.6kbits/s speed=1.11x
frame=  118 fps= 75 q=28.0 size=     698kB time=00:00:02.40 bitrate=2381.4kbits/s speed=1.54x
frame=  154 fps= 75 q=28.0 size=    1083kB time=00:00:03.84 bitrate=2311.1kbits/s speed=1.86x
...
```

Thank you!

Edit: as suggested by @kesh, I have changed `h264` to `rawvideo`, the arguments now are: `-i pipe: -f rawvideo -pix_fmt bgr24 -an -sn pipe:`

Here's the output of ffmpeg:

```
Input #0, h264, from 'pipe:':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/bt470bg/smpte170m, progressive), 1080x2256, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> rawvideo (native))
// About 9 of these "No accelerated colorspace..." message
[swscaler @ 0x128690000] [swscaler @ 0x1286a0000] No accelerated colorspace conversion found from yuv420p to bgr24.
Output #0, rawvideo, to 'pipe:':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf59.16.100
  Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (BGR[24] / 0x18524742), bgr24(pc, gbr/bt470bg/smpte170m, progressive), 1080x2256, q=2-31, 1461888 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbn
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc59.18.100 rawvideo
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x
// FFmpeg outputs no more log after this
```

Comment: What you probably want is raw RGB image (not H.264 encoded bitstream). Try `-f rawvideo` instead of `-f h264`

Comment: @kesh, I tried that and still got a black image. Do you think that maybe ffmpeg didn't receive the full data? Maybe the byte array size for my image (width * height * 3) is wrong?

Comment: I forgot to mention, the image file is not completely black. There is a portion of the image on top, and the color seems to be wrong: https://imgur.com/a/XvOFGcy

Comment: You are reading a correct number of bytes. Does the Output log saying "rawvideo" and "bgr24" now? (I suggest updating your post with the `rawvideo` run) Also, have you tried with a known local video file?

Comment: I have updated the post with `rawvideo` option. Please let me know if you see anything wrong, thank you!

Comment: FFmpeg-wise, it looks good to my eyes. (I don't think "No accelerated colorspace conversion found" message is a big deal.) One other thing to check is what happens if you capture say 10 frames? Can it be that the first frame is always black? Outside of that, I'd try to isolate your input and output (use known input file or output to a file).

Comment: Thank you @kesh! The problem was in my Read method, it should be: `int n = baseStream.Read(decoded, numBytesRead, numBytesToRead)`